# Avoid too much dependencies for a Use Case in a Clean Architecture app

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, composition, clean-architecture

### Context

I'm currently developing an application following the *Clean Architecture* principles (at least I'm trying really hard to follow these).

All my Dependency Injections are done manually, without any Framework.

One of my Use Case consists of the user being able to answer to a question he was asked.

- If he/she is wrong, nothing happens, he can try again
- If he/she is right, a list of things happens :

  - I get back his/her current session, and modify the state of that session. (**Update session** step - DB read)
  - I get back a contact record from the database (**Get Contact** step - DB read)
  - I send a mail into an in-app mailbox with this contact information (basically it's a database insert of a message) (**Send Mail** step - DB write)
  - I save the updated session (**Save session** step - DB write)
  - I push an event into a custom Message Queue (**Programm event** step - Queue write)

### Issue

All of the work described above are the steps I need to go through if the user answer to this question; it's kind of an Application Logic. For that reason, I created a specific `AnswerQuestionUseCase` which do all of this.

Because of all these databases interactions, I now have 5 dependencies injected into my Use Case, and I'm starting to think this is a **code smell** of bad design.
The unit test of this class is ugly, not quite readable with all these mocks.

### Solution ?

I searched a bit how to deal with this issue, and I found that **Function Composition** might be a good way to avoid so many dependencies, but I've found that if a go that way, all of the Application Logic would go outside of my Use Case, deported into the presenter maybe.

I could also break my Use Case into smaller Use Cases, but that just hide the issue, pushing the dependencies elsewhere.

I thought the Use Case was a block of Application Logic which you couldn't break apart for a specific use case of your app.

Is my understanding of what should be a Use Case any good ? How would you deal with that many dependencies ? How would you use Composition over DI to avoid so many mocks inside the unit test of this case ?

Comment: `UseCase` is totally agnostic to concepts like `Session` or `Sending an Email if...` or `Program event`. These things happen in different layers due to different reasons. Are not you, maybe, missing a service layer where to orchestrate whatever happens *after* the use case? Or a system of callbacks, error handling, etc.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Right now the `Use Case` manipulate these concepts via interfaces. What would the service you're talking about look like in this case ? 
I'm afraid about just moving some work at another level (service), then having nothing to do inside the UC but calling the newly created service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer I know of is to separate the bits that consume the data from the bits that provide the data.

The bit that knows about the *application specific business rules* is just an in memory state machine -- aka an "object" -- with a *data* interface.

Separate from that is the *protocol*, the bit of logic that understands how to move the data from one place to another.  This is the bit of code that coordinates the flow of data between the different dependencies.  In other words, this code knows how to *route* the data from one place to another, but doesn't usually need to *inspect* the data.

So you test the application specific business rules by instantiating the object in your test, and passing data to it directly.

You test the protocol by using test doubles.

In some cases, the protocol can be broken down into logical units that don't involve all of the dependencies.  In that case, you can write tests that focus on the smaller units, with tests that focus on the coordination between a subset of the dependencies, rather than all of them.

You might find these talks helpful:

- Cory Benfield: [Building Protocol Libraries the Right Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U)
- Gary Bernhardt: [Boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries)

Comment: If I understand, you wouldn't consider the _protocol_ as application specific business rules ? My understanding about the Use Cases (application business rules) was that **everything** that had to be done for a particular use case is part of that, including the flow of data, since this flow must always be the same application-wise for this use case.

Comment: **everything** involves too many things. "Answering a question" has nothing to do with sending an email if X or publishing an event if Y or updating a session of Z. *Session*, *emails*, *logs*, *notifications* can be executed as business side-effects instead of forcing them explicitly from the business itself.  **The business layers is not the application**, the application is built upon the business.

Comment: Exactly, following the Clean Architecture principles (https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), _Use Case_ is application layer, and _Entity_ is business layer. 
If I understand your comment @Laiv, I can keep this side effects' flow in the Use Case (app layer) and create an Entity which will only validate the answer (pure function, no mocks).

Comment: "the circles are schematic. You may find that you need more than just these four. There’s no rule that says you must always have just these four. However, The Dependency Rule always applies. Source code dependencies always point inwards."